# Alternative way convert int ? to double?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, .net-4.5

Is there any way to convert this ?

```
public int? intVal ;
public double? dblVal ;
```

How I am working now

```
if(dblVal==null)
    intVal =null;
else
    intVal = Convert.ToInt32(dblVal);
```

Any alternative way  ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: If the behavior of Convert.ToInt32 is doing what you want, then this is an acceptable way. Alternatively you could inline everything like this: `intval = (dblVal == null) ? null : Convert.ToInt32(dblVal);`

Comment: @IanP: That won't compile, because the compiler won't be able to figure out the type of the conditional expression. You'd need to cast either the second or third operand to `int?`, or use `default(int?)` or something similar.

Comment: You can go to string first and then parse int from string

Comment: @T.S.: Why would you want to do that? It wouldn't even work without some effort, as you can't parse non-integer values with `int.Parse` (e.g. `int.Parse("5.5")` will throw an exception)

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct. I don't say it is THE way, but as question implies, it is an "Alternative way..."

Comment: @T.S.: Well you *could* send it to a web service to do the conversion - but it wouldn't in any way be a *useful* way. I think the OP is really asking for *sensible* alternatives, and I don't view unnecessary string conversions as falling in that category.

Comment: @JonSkeet Web service would probably do one of those anyways, right? And while sending it, wouldn't you sometimes serialize values to strings (XML) and deserialize them back? There we go - to string and back, used all over the place

Comment: @T.S.: Uh, yes - when string conversions are *necessary*, that's fine. My point is that it's the wrong approach here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just cast:

```
intVal = (int?) dblVal;
```

This will already result in a `null` value if `dblVal` is null. Note that unlike `Convert.ToInt32(double)`, this does *not* result in an exception if `dblVal` is outside the range of `int`. If that's a concern, you should work out exactly what you want to achieve.

From the C# 5 spec, section 6.2.3:

> Explicit nullable conversions permit predefined explicit conversions that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types. For each of the predefined explicit conversions that convert from a non-nullable value type S to a non-nullable value type T (§6.1.1, §6.1.2, §6.1.3, §6.2.1, and §6.2.2), the following nullable conversions exist:
>
> - An explicit conversion from S? to T?.
> - An explicit conversion from S to T?.
> - An explicit conversion from S? to T.
>
> Evaluation of a nullable conversion based on an underlying conversion from S to T proceeds as follows:
>
> - If the nullable conversion is from S? to T?:
>
>   - If the source value is null (HasValue property is false), the result is the null value of type T?.
>   - Otherwise, the conversion is evaluated as an unwrapping from S? to S, followed by the underlying conversion from S to T, followed by a wrapping from T to T?.
> - ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
intVal = dblVal.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(dblVal.Value) : (int?)null;
```